# Convert 2D SVGs to 3D Models not working correctly

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, svg

I simply want to convert a SVG into a 3D Model.

Steps:

1. import SVG
2. Convert it to Mesh
3. Extrude everything
4. Export

The problem is that my SVG's are not displayed correctly..

Here is my SVG: https://gofile.io/d/IJ1rKV

But this is how it ends up:

[exported .daw file](https://gofile.io/d/FbY2pi)

What am I missing here? If I just try that with a simple (one color svg) it is working as expected but with more complex SVG's Blenders seems to struggle. How can I fix this?

This is how it looks:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: hi, in that particular example you should delete the outer box, the first curve that acts as a a paper... don't know about the other files, maybe it's related

Comment: @alambre hi, thanks for your help but I actually want that "paper"

Comment: Image has white rect at background, remove it, and you will get expected result

Comment: @Crantisz I want the white rect background :D

Comment: so what's the problem then?

Comment: @Crantisz look at the screenshot, the text is flickering

Comment: It will, if you extrude white plane at the same distance as text, this is called z-fighting